# how to declare variable in c++ i dont want to define it so it should not consume any memory just declaration?

Tags: c++

When we write int a,compiler gives memory to int a, but now i just want to tell compiler that variable is integer but don't wanna compiler to give any memory to a.

Comment: So what do you want it to do?

Comment: How do you intend to use a variable for which there is no allocated storage?

Comment: @cdhowie: You can use it in an unevaluated context, e.g. as an argument to `sizeof` or `decltype`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour `typedef`s (or `using` aliases) can also be used with `sizeof`, would make `decltype` redundant, and are a much better way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 6):

If it's a global variable, then use `extern` to make it a pure declaration:

```
extern int a;
```

It will still need to be defined somewhere, if the program uses it.

If it's a local variable, then you can't declare it without defining it; it will be created when the program reaches the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can say this:

```
extern int a;
```

This way there will be no storage allocated for `a` here, and the linker will look for the symbol `a` in another module when building your executable.  If it's not found you will get a linker error.  This is expected, because you can't have a variable which doesn't exist.